Override default UTC time on static resources
I have set up static resource serving with SpringBoot like so:
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/data/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:data/");
    }
}

And when I'm trying to fetch the resource on the /data endpoint, I get the file I requested, but the headers Date and Last-Modified seem to be in UTC time zone format. I tried manually setting the default time zone to Europe/Zagreb and doing:
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now());

Prints the expected result, but if I do:
System.out.println(Files.getLastModifiedTime(Paths.get(lastProcessedPath)));

I get the time in UTC, the same thing with fetching files on the configured resource endpoint, as mentioned earlier.
I tried using Filters but unsuccessfully, because if I call doFilter() before I do any logic to setting the custom Headers, the response is returned and then modified, but if I try doing any logic before doFilter() I don't know what resource is in question and can't know last modified data.
I'm not sure whether something like that can be achieved using ResourceResolver interface - documentation is quite confusing on that one.

Thank you @aled for pointing me to the post in question(Timezone for Expires and Last-Modified HTTP Headers). It seems that the spring implementation doesn't allow the Last-Modified header modification due to the RFC specification, it is automatically returned in GMT format. I tried manipulating the response headers using ResourceResolver and ResourceTransformer objects, but the response object is not available through those so, not modifiable - again, could be because of the RFC specification.

I may be misinterpreting the case here,
if the issue is about setting the zone to use and mapping it
you could send your local date time to a ZonedDateTime then use that to print using a formatter
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, "Europe/Zagreb")
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
return zonedDateTime.format(formatter);


Mapping to the correct time is not the problem. Putting the correct time in the response header Date and Last-Modified is the problem.

did you tried setting headers data in your logic
